# Getting an error InvalidArgumentError: indices[10,0] = 92379 is not in [0, 92379) because of vocab size mismatching

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, lstm, embedding

I am trying to learn LSTM for the first time, Basically concatenating two LSTM layers. Below is model architecture.

---

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 3)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            (None, 23)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_2 (Embedding)         (None, 3, 300)       27713700    input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_3 (Embedding)         (None, 23, 300)      240724500   input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                   (None, 300)          721200      embedding_2[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                   (None, 300)          721200      embedding_3[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 600)          0           lstm_1[0][0]                     
                                                                 lstm_2[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            601         concatenate_1[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 269,881,201
Trainable params: 1,443,001
Non-trainable params: 268,438,200
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Code for one of the LSTM Layer.

```
# Query LSTM
max_query_length = 3
length_query_vocab = 92379
EMBEDDING_DIM = 300
batch_size = 1024

queryLSTM = Input(shape=(max_query_length, ))
queryLSTMx = Embedding(length_query_vocab, EMBEDDING_DIM, weights=[query_embedding_matrix],trainable=False)(queryLSTM)
queryLSTMx = LSTM(EMBEDDING_DIM, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, max_query_length, EMBEDDING_DIM), input_shape=(max_query_length, EMBEDDING_DIM))(queryLSTMx)
```

I am getting below error:

```
Train on 4240822 samples, validate on 471203 samples
Epoch 1/2
  70880/4240822 [..............................] - ETA: 6:40:34 - loss: 0.3239 - acc: 0.9021
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-3a0bd454aae9> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit([Xq_train, Xp_train], y, epochs=2, validation_split=0.1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1037                                         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1038                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1039                                         validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1040 
   1041     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
    197                     ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    198 
--> 199                 outs = f(ins_batch)
    200                 outs = to_list(outs)
    201                 for l, o in zip(out_labels, outs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2713                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2714 
-> 2715             return self._call(inputs)
   2716         else:
   2717             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2673             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   2674         else:
-> 2675             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
   2676         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
   2677 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
   1440         if run_metadata:
   1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: indices[10,0] = 92379 is not in [0, 92379)
     [[{{node embedding_2/embedding_lookup}} = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_2/embeddings/read, embedding_2/Cast, embedding_2/embedding_lookup/axis)]]
```

I strongly believe that issue is because 92379 is out of index. But I am not able to figure out where is the root cause.

EDIT: I am running this code on Google Colab TPU. With GPU it seems to be working fine.

Comment: what is the vocabulary size? It should be the first argument of  Embedding layer(92379)

Comment: Vocab size is 92379, I read it somewhere in the SO that running the same code on GPU not throwing this issue.

I have edited my original post.